# login not working in CD environment

Tags: federated-authentication

I have developed login functionality using Sitecore federated authentication which includes user registration, reset & forgot password, update password etc. the functionality works fine in CM environment but login is not working in CD environment( **AuthenticationManager.Login returns null** ). However registration works fine in both the environments.

In CD logs, I can see an warning log - **Accessing disabled functionality: Authentication** message

Is there any configuration specific to CD environment that is supposed to be enabled?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: Sitecore 10.1.3

Comment: Please try adding ContentDelivery to role:require in this file Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config. More info here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36718/login-redirecting-to-401-only-on-cd-server-after-upgrade-to-xp-10-3